# Add path element after last / in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory path like /abc/def/ghi and I want to add one more element after the last "/", so it should be /abc/def/xyz/ghi .

```
 dir="/abc/def/ghi"
 findStr="/"
 replaceStr="/xyz/"
 finalPath=${dir/%findStr/replaceStr}
```

But if I echo $finalPath, it is the same as $dir, nothing has been added.  Can someone let me know what's wrong with my code.  I got the replacement systax from 
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html,

```
   ${string/%substring/replacement}
   If $substring matches back end of $string, substitute $replacement for $substring.
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the ABS is in general a very poor choice of references -- it very often showcases bad practices, if not outright inaccuracies. Consider the bash-hackers wiki or the Wooledge wiki instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Quoting below is optional, for the benefit of SO's syntax highlighting
finalPath="${dir%/*}/xyz/${dir##*/}"
```

This works in three stages:

- `${dir%/*}` removes the last `/` and everything after it
- `/xyz/` expands to itself, of course
- `${dir##*/}` removes everything *before* the last `/`

---

As for the anchoring syntax used in the original, [this is discussed in the bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), in the Anchoring subheading under ["Search and Replace"](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace):

> *Anchoring* - Additionally you can "anchor" an expression: A `#` (hashmark) will indicate that your expression is matched against the beginning portion of the string, a `%` (percent-sign) will do it for the end portion.
>
> ```
> MYSTRING=xxxxxxxxxx
> echo ${MYSTRING/#x/y}  # RESULT: yxxxxxxxxx
> echo ${MYSTRING/%x/y}  # RESULT: xxxxxxxxxy
> ```

However, this matches **at the end**, not simply at the location *nearest* the end. Thus, `${dir/%$findStr/$replaceStr}` would work if `$dir` *ended* in a `/`, which isn't the case for the data provided.

Comment: Thanks.  I just updated the post.  I got the replacement syntax from http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html, 
   ${string/%substring/replacement}
   If $substring matches back end of $string, substitute $replacement for $substring.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification -- I've amended to address the syntax in question, and why it didn't work as intended.